# How would I stream audio from pytube to FFMPEG and discord.py without downloading and converting beforehand

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, python-asyncio

I have a discord.py bot setup in a small server of mine. I have setup a music command that downloads a song from YouTube and outputs it into a VC. At the moment, the command downloads the full song, converts it, and *then* outputs it into a VC, but this process is heavily slow. How would I go about streaming the audio directly into the VC? I'm open to use youtube_dl in place of pytube3. I don't care much about smaller code optimizations as this is just a small bot for a few friends and me.

Thanks for any input!

```
@bot.command()
async def play(ctx, *song):
    if ctx.author.voice is None or ctx.author.voice.channel is None:
        await ctx.send("You aren't in a VC!")
        return
    print(song) #debugging
    os.system("rm music.mp3")
    ydl_opts = {
        'noplaylist': True,        
        'outtmpl': 'music',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '128',
        }],
    'format': '139',  
    }
    youtube = pytube.YouTube(str(song).strip("(,)'"))
    video = youtube.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()
    await ctx.send("downloading")
    video.download(filename="music")
    await ctx.send("converting...")
    os.system("ffmpeg -i music.mp4 -map 0:a:0 -b:a 96k music.mp3")
    
    voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    vc = await voice_channel.connect()
    vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('music.mp3'), after=lambda e: print('done', e))
    while vc.is_playing():
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already using `youtube_dl` (judging by your `ydl_opts` var). What you can do is:

- Installing youtube_dl (`pip install youtube-dl`) if you don't have it.
- Install requests (`pip install requests`)
- Extract the video info:

  ```py
  from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL
  from requests import get

  #Get videos from links or from youtube search
  def search(query):
      with YoutubeDL({'format': 'bestaudio', 'noplaylist':'True'}) as ydl:
          try: requests.get(arg)
          except: info = ydl.extract_info(f"ytsearch:{arg}", download=False)['entries'][0]
          else: info = ydl.extract_info(arg, download=False)
      return (info, info['formats'][0]['url'])
  ```
- Make the bot join the channel:

  ```py
  async def join(ctx, voice):
      channel = ctx.author.voice.channel

      if voice and voice.is_connected():
          await voice.move_to(channel)
      else:
          voice = await channel.connect()
  ```
- Play the video:

  ```py
  from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio
  from discord.ext import commands
  from discord.utils import get


  @bot.command()
  async def play(ctx, *, query):
      #Solves a problem I'll explain later
      FFMPEG_OPTS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}

      video, source = search(query)
      voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

      await join(ctx, voice)
      await ctx.send(f'Now playing {info['title']}.')

      voice.play(FFmpegPCMAudio(source, **FFMPEG_OPTS), after=lambda e: print('done', e))
      voice.is_playing()
  ```
- To know what the `video` variable contains, you can print it.
- However, streaming audio causes a known issue, [explained here](https://support.discord.com/hc/fr/articles/360035010351--Known-Issue-Music-Bots-Not-Playing-Music-From-Certain-Sources). To solve this problem, you have to use that `FFMPEG_OPTS` variable. It will reconnect the bot to the source so it's still able to stream the video, when this happens, you'll have a strange message in your terminal that you don't need to be worried of.
- Note that there's no error management, you'll have to do it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Sadly at this line: `voice = get(self.bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)`, the code throws this error: `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`. I tried defining "self" in `async def play(self, ctx, *, query):`, but that threw this error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'guild'`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: My bad, it's `voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)` (I took a part of my code and forgot to delete self)

Comment: Won't the use of `requests` (a blocking API) block the whole event loop? Also, where is `get` defined?

Comment: Using `requests` won't block anything. The `get()` method I use in `play` comes from `discord.utils`, I forgot to import it in my code ^^ If you want separate names, you can write `from discord.utils import get as dget`

Comment: Thank you! That worked! I had to change `voice.play(FFmpegPCMAudio)...` to `voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio)...`, but it all works! Ty!

Comment: I also replaced the get() line with my own join function

Comment: *Using requests won't block anything* - Can you clarify this? `requests.get` is a blocking API, so it definitely blocks the event loop until completed.